# Platform event trigger not execute based on publish records

Tags: platform-event

I am publishing platform event from apex trigger but the problem which I am facing when I am updating account record with data loader and record size is 50 then 50 times platform event are published but platform event trigger is executing only 47 times and some time exeucte 50 times ?

here is code which i am publish from account trigger

```
public static void createPlatformEventRecords(List<FinServ__FinancialAccount__c>new_List){
    System.debug('--before publish event---');
    Financial_Account_Event__e ev =new Financial_Account_Event__e();
    ev.Publish__c=true;
    ev.Financial_Account_Record_Id__c =new_List[0].Id;
    EventBus.publish(ev);
    System.debug('--after publish event---');
}
```

here is platform event trigger

```
public static void onAfterInsert(List<Financial_Account_Event__e>list_New){ 
   System.debug('platform event triggger execute);
}
```

If any one have idea Please help.

Comment: Check how many platform events are passed to each execution?

Comment: thanks PhilW for comments, Yes I am checking every events and i am using below of codeList<Database.SaveResult> results = EventBus.publish(inkEvents);

// Inspect publishing result for each event
for (Database.SaveResult sr : results) {
    if (sr.isSuccess()) {
        System.debug('Successfully published event.');
    } else {
        for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('Error returned: ' +
                        err.getStatusCode() +
                        ' - ' +
                        err.getMessage());
        }
    }       
}

Comment: I more meant you could log the "list_New" size to see if you get some events together in a single call to the PE trigger-based subscriber.

Comment: Sorry Phil for delay response, Yes you are correct this is happening in PE trigger some time list_New size is two. thanks for support.